# CoffeeScript function not triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I have several inputs generated by a loop inside a show page. They all have the same `name`. When of of them is unfocused, I'd like to call a JS script. However the signal is never triggered. Why?

**expenses.js.coffee**

```
alert 'Test' // This instruction is detected

$("input[value='nb_kms[]']").blur -> // This one is not
   alert 'Handler for .blur() called.'
return
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<% @calendar.each_with_index do |d, i| %>       
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="nb_kms[]" value="<%= @nb_kms[i] %>"></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
$("body").on "blur", "input[value='nb_kms[]']", ()->
```

or do this, add `class` to the input

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="number" name="nb_kms[]" value="<%= @nb_kms[i] %>" class="kms_input"></td>
</tr>
```

in js

```
ready = ()->
  $("body").on "blur", ".kms_input", ()->
    alert $(this).val()
    alert 'Handler for .blur() called.'

$(document).ready ready
$(document).on 'page:load', ready
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work. That's weird because I don't any JS errors. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Isn't this misplaced arguments?  Shouldn't it be: `$("body").on 'blur', "input[value='nb_kms[]']", ->`?  The event should come before the selector.  Also, you do not need the open and close parenthesis as there aren't any parameters being passed.

Comment: I'm getting an alert message at the initialization of the page but not after. However it's a step forward!

Comment: Are you using rails4?

Comment: Yes and yes. Keep in mind the alerts are called at the initialization of the page but not after. All my inputs are ignored.

Comment: Okay I got your problem, give a sec

Comment: Check my edit, that was happening due to turbolinks, you need to use `page:load` event along with `document.ready`, try it out!

Comment: Done! Could you please remove the `var` keyword in your answer? It's generating an ExecJS::RuntimeError at initialization.